# How can I tell if HttpClient is connecting via HTTPS

Tags: c#, .net, https, httpclient

I am using `HttpClient` to talk to an API.  The server will automatically redirect `http://` requests to `https://` if enabled.  So, in order to protect the users API key I want to create a test connection to the website to see if I am redirected before sending over the API Key.

The `HttpClient` redirects properly, but I cannot seem to find a decent way to find out if the client is using HTTPS or not. I know I could test whether `https://` exists within `response.RequestMessage.RequestUri` but this seems a little flaky

```
public void DetectTransportMethod()
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);

        using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(this.HttpHostname).Result)
        {
            using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
            {
                // check if the method is HTTPS or not
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of `HttpClient` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)) and `HttpResponseMessage` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage(v=vs.118).aspx)) do not contain any methods that can be used to determine whether a request has been made over https. Even though checking the URI of the `HttpResponseMessage` does indeed sound flaky I'm afraid it's the easiest and most readable option. Implementing this as a extension method for `HttpResponseMessage` probably is the most readable. To ensure that the `HttpClient` you are using can be redirected make sure that the `WebRequestHandler` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.webrequesthandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) passed into the `HttpClient` has the `AllowAutoRedirect` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.allowautoredirect(v=vs.110).aspx)) property set to true.

See the following extension method:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsSecure(this HttpResponseMessage message)
    {
        rreturn message.RequestMessage.RequestUri.Scheme == "https";
    }
}
```

And the following Console application that demonstrates it works. For this to work however, the HTTP server has to upgrade the connection to https (Like Facebook does) and the `AllowAutoRedirect` property of the `WebRequestHandler` has to be set to `true`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { AllowAutoRedirect = true}))
     {
         client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);

         using (var response = client.GetAsync("http://www.geenstijl.nl").Result)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(response.IsSecure());
         }

         using (var response = client.GetAsync("http://www.facebook.com").Result)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(response.IsSecure());
         }
     }

     Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `message.RequestMessage.RequestUri.ToString().ToLower().StartsWith("https://")` you can just use `message.RequestMessage.RequestUri.Scheme == "https"`